# "Quiet will leave enemies awestruck" is this an effect?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

When using Quiet as a buddy it says that if you give her the golden skin/cameo then it will leave enemy soldiers "awestruck"

Is this an actual effect that will distract soldiers or is it just for show kind of thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From personal experience and from what I've read on other sites, Quiet's different outfits do not provide any additional skills despite what might be suggested on the in-game description.

Comment: Don't want to sound rude my man, do you have anything to back that up:)?

Comment: @ModCloud No worries - Apart from personal experience and others asking similar questions on other sites, I've got no definitive source.

Comment: Okay dude, well going on that then from my own experience to I guess you are right

Comment: @ModCloud It probably makes her easier to spot, if it is anything like the golden skin for Venom Snake. That usually does not matter though because she usually is too far away to be seen without shooting her sniper rifle first.

Comment: None of the cosmetic outfits (Quiet's silver and gold, Snake's gold skin, Cyber Ninja outfit, etc.) seem to affect stealth or visibility one way or the other in-game.